# How do I "authorize this computer" with the latest version of Music (which doesn't have an Account menu anymore)?

Tags: music, itunes-match

When I try to download a file from the cloud (I'm using Apple's match/subscription thing) it just says

> This computer is not authorized.
> You must authorize this computer before you can use Apple Music or iTunes Match on this comptuer

I am logged into my Apple ID/icloud etc on this Mac. Everything else seems to work fine. Photos sync, iCloud files, etc. Apple's Help menu for "authorize" even still says to do so under the "Account" menu... but Music 1.0.6.10 (along with the latest MacOS) does not have an Account menu.

Answer (score 1):

If you enable "iTunes store" under the Disable settings, that removes the Account menu entirely. Box unchecked, and then I can simply authorize the computer exactly as you'd normally do.

`*derp*` Why *on earth* did I turn the parental controls on?